# Lua determining when out of range

Tags: loops, while-loop, lua

I have a function called preprocess. It looks like this

```
  function image_utils.preprocess(meanfile, oneD_image_table)
      local img_mean = torch.load(meanfile).img_mean:transpose(3,1)
      return function()
           for t_class, img_path in pairs(oneD_image_table) do
              local im3 = image.load(img_path)
              local im4 = image.scale(im3,227,227,'bilinear')*25
              return im4 - image.scale(img_mean, 227, 227, 'bilinear')  

      end
end
```

Here's how I call it:

```
 im_f = image_util.preprocess(meanfile, path_list)
 repeat
    im=im_f()
    batch[count]:copy(im)
    count = count + 1

 until count == batchSize
```

This works. However, I would like to be detect when im_f doesn't have any more iterations left and use that to determine when I should stop looping.In other words, something like this:

```
  repeat 
    im = im_f()
    count = count+1
    batch[count] = im
  until im == nil (or im is some sentinel value that tells me to stop)
```

However, I have not been able to make this work due to out of range error.

In short, I want to loop until im_f tells me to stop; rather than using a predetermined number to tell me when to stop.

Comment: What does `image_utils.preprocess` have to do with `copy()`? What is `im_f()`? What about that attempt didn't work?

Comment: "I have not been able to make this work" tells us nothing. You need to start [stripping away all your project specific code](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#volume) in an effort to present a stand-alone example that we can help with. 90% of the time, you'll solve your own problem. If you don't, you'll have something you can present to us that we can actually work with, rather than a subset of code which doesn't even contain the problem mixed in with a lot of superfluous code simply distracts.

Comment: The top code doesn't even compile, and the for loop doesn't make sense since you unconditionally return in the loop's body.

Comment: @Mud Perhaps I should have said "I do not see how to do this." In other words, don't interpret it as I attempted something and I can't find the bug, but rather, I don't see how you can do this in Lua. And if you must know about the "attempt" that didn't work is that I get an out of range error.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo It might not compile if you don't have all the right packages installed and some other code. But the loop makes sense. It's essentially a way of building an iterator. see http://www.lua.org/pil/6.1.html

Comment: @EtanReisner You raise some good points. im_f is the anonymous inner function in the first code block. Other questions are more or less addressed in other comments.

Comment: The loop doesn't make sense. Do you see a loop in the iterator example in the example in the link you provided? And it's syntactically invalid; the `for` loop is missing its `end`.

Comment: You are correct. I caught a very big bug in my (admittedly, toy) solution. Thanks.

Comment: You could always try using pcall to catch the 'out of range error'. Something like:
`local success, im = pcall(im_f);
if not success then break end`
Probably not the solution you're looking for, but it might work.